# Is it possible to get only opinion based tweets from twitter APIs or any other dataset?

Tags: data-request, api, social-media

Opinion based tweets such as Product X is portable, has a good performance etc. Using the search API, i get mostly promotional tweets and after filtering i am left with almost nothing.

Comment: Do you need a corpus of opinion based tweets or a method to find them in real time ?